# Doc doesn't show the BibTeX-Key of citavi

Tags: citing, cite-package

In citavi I can setup the settings to use citations for references.
But I always get the references with the number 0. I need the reference as follows: [AnfG], but get: (0)

I don't know what the problem of citavi is :(

[image]

I don't know what I have to do..

Comment: Citavi is a tool that has nothing to do with LaTeX. You can tell citavi to typeset little hearts instead of the dot above the  `i`. Citavi exports a bib file and LaTeX (or rather bst-files) control the output.

Comment: Try  `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` instead of the current bibliographystyle line.

Comment: @Johannes_B Now it shows (Eis15) in the text but I want to use it like so [Eis15] and in my References list have to be [Eis15] behind the reference like: [Eis15] Bonnie Eisenman. Learning React Native

Comment: @Johannes_B do you know how to show the URL of an internet link in my references?

Comment: You are using a style from the end of the 80, nobody would have ever guessed that they will include urls in the future. The style just does not support it. Better use the mor modern package `biblatex` where every styles supports an url field.

Comment: If you don't want to use the modern biblatex, you can use the `note` fields as described in the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Including_URLs_in_bibliography). Look at the many many hacks there, all very easy with `biblatex` ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I have an own .bst file. I get an error when I'm using  \bibliographystyle{acl}. The error message is: Paragraph ended before \NAT@apalk was complete.

Comment: Comments of a Q-A-site aren't the right place to have a discussion. I suggest to move over to LaTeX-community, a proper discussion forum where we can slowly find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the error.

The only way what I have to do, was to write the following package in the header:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```